# Criar uma função cheia de elementos e que retorna dois valores em php

Tags: php

Como posso fazer uma função com esse código, já que terei que repeti-lo várias vezes e as únicas coisas que mudam são as variáveis $a e $b. Eu preciso usar no meu html o retorno das duas variáveis resultantes ($titulo e $subtitulo).

```
$situacao = 0;
$sql =  "SELECT * FROM `ed_painel` where (idaluno = '$id' or idaluno = '$id2') and a = '$a' and b ='$b' ;"; 
$result = $conn->query($sql); 
if ($result->num_rows > 0) {
while($row = $result->fetch_assoc()) {
$situacao =  $row["situacao"];
$obs =  $row["obs"];
} }

if ($situacao > 3 and $situacao < 7) {
    $titulo = "AGUARDE";    }
else {
    $titulo = "PENDENTE";
    $subtitulo = '$obs';
   }
```

Sei que não é assim, mas seria algo como isso:

```
funcaoteste (1,2) //variáveis $a e $b
<h1> $titulo </h1> <br>
<h2> $subtitulo </h2> <br>


funcaoteste (7,3) //variáveis $a e $b
<h1> $titulo </h1> <br>
<h2> $subtitulo </h2> <br>


funcaoteste (4,1) //variáveis $a e $b
<h1> $titulo </h1> <br>
<h2> $subtitulo </h2> <br>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

O PHP não pode retornar múltiplos valores diretamente (o que é possível no Golang e no VLang, por exemplo). Você deverá usar um "array" para isso, seria a forma mais fácil, poderá usar o `list()` para simplificar o processo.

Portanto:

```
function funcaoteste(int $a, int $b) : array { 
    $situacao = 0;
    $sql = "SELECT * FROM `ed_painel` WHERE (idaluno = '$id' OR idaluno = '$id2') AND a = '$a' AND b ='$b' ;";
    $result = $conn->query($sql);
    if ($result->num_rows > 0) {
        while ($row = $result->fetch_assoc()) {
            $situacao = $row["situacao"];
            $obs = $row["obs"];
        }
    }

    if ($situacao > 3 && $situacao < 7) {
        return ["AGUARDE", ""];
    }

    return ["PENDENTE", $obs];
}
```

Então, poderia usar como:

```
[$titulo, $subtitulo] = funcaoteste(1,2)
<h1> $titulo </h1> <br>
<h2> $subtitulo </h2> <br>
```

> Isso deve funcionar somente nas versões mais recentes do PHP. Estou ignorando outros problemas no código.

---

*Você também pode retornar algo como `["titulo": $t, "subtitulo": $st]` e usar algo como `$resposta_do_funcaoteste["titulo"]`.*

Comment: Amigo, obrigado por ajudar. Ao testar, me deparo com o seguinte erro :                                  
 Fatal error: Uncaught Error: Call to a member function query() on null in .... on line 59. Tenha ideia do que pode ser?

Comment: @Navegador eu apenas copie o seu próprio código, a linha deve ser a `$result = $conn->query($sql);`, você deve definir o `$conn`, assim como os `$id` e `$id2`.

Comment: Perfeito amigo, realmente era isso, MUITO OBRIGADO.